# Query in dsrm command

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, batch-file

I need to remove 1000 computers from AD. I tried the script below, but it's not working.  When I used `dsmod` to disable computers, in the same script, it works.

```
@echo off
set ComputerList=C:\Users\a058059x\Desktop\Machines.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%ComputerList%"') do (
    echo Processing %%a ...
    dsquery computer -name "%%a" | dsrm
)
```

Can anyone help me to correct the error in this script?

Comment: Could you share what you mean by "not working"? Any error messages? By default, `dsrm` will prompt to remove each object. Using `dsrm -noprompt` enables non-interactive mode.

Comment: Tip: Instead of using having the `for` command type the text file, why not just put file name in? I've occasionally run into encoding issues, when typing a text file instead of reading directly. Try `for /f "delims=" %%a in (%ComputerList%)` or `for /f "delims= usebackq" %%a in ("%ComputerList%")` if you need to support paths with spaces.

Comment: i am getting  dsrm failed:'-name' is an unknown parameter. this error.  when run via command line its working.

Comment: when i run this command

@echo off
set ComputerList=C:\Users\a058059x\Desktop\Machines.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%ComputerList%") do (
echo Processing %%a ...
dsquery computer -name "%%a" | dsrm -noprompt >> result.txt
)

i am getting the error : Target object for this command' is missing...

Comment: Is here a reason you're using the ds tools and batch instead of PowerShell with the Active Directory module?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using powershell to accomplish this?  The command is Remove-ADComputer.

Your command would look like this:

```
Get-Content COMPUTERLIST.txt | Get-Computer | Remove-ADComputer -recursive
```

assuming you have ADWS installed